# Add events to a custom calendar with an arraylist?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a custom calendar where i want to add events to, the info is from an arraylist and the info came from a JSON file. The event tag is really ugly too, I would like to change it to a drawable but I'm not sure how either.

I'm fairly new at this and not sure where to start, I already have the events displayed underneath the calendarView, if anyone can help with formatting that list that would he helpful too. For now I'm individually adding two just for a test but realistically I can't do that for all the events year long.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ArrayList<ListModel> ListModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        //SearchView simpleSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

        textViewDate = findViewById(R.id.date);
        textViewEvent = findViewById(R.id.event);

        final CollapsibleCalendar collapsibleCalendar = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

        collapsibleCalendar.setCalendarListener(new CollapsibleCalendar.CalendarListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDaySelect() {
                //show events for that day
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataUpdate() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMonthChange() {
                //list events from month
                //FBToast.infoToast(MainActivity.this,"This is Info Toast",FBToast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }

            @Override
            public void onWeekChange(int i) {
                //list events for the week
            }

        });


        collapsibleCalendar.setState(UICalendar.STATE_EXPANDED);

        collapsibleCalendar.addEventTag(2019, 04, 01);
        collapsibleCalendar.addEventTag(2019, 04, 02);

        requestJSON();


    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Could you [edit] your question and make sure you have a clear concise problem statements ?

Comment: I would like to see your json response for addEventTag

Comment: what i want to do is add the events in the arraylist into the calendar as events and have them show up on the calendarview, i want to use the title, start date and end date as necesarry info